# execute bash function from makefile

Tags: bash, make

as far as I know, it is not possible to execute bash functions in a makefile, so I put them in a external shell script and I call the script from the Makefile. running the script directly works well, but running through the makefile throws the error:

```
 make deploy_staging 
./deploy.sh
./deploy.sh: 1: ./deploy.sh: function: not found
publishing 
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument --function-name: expected one argument
./deploy.sh: 4: ./deploy.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'deploy_staging' failed
make: *** [deploy_staging] Error 2
```

this is my deploy.sh script (the one that works if executed directly):

```
function publish {
  echo "publishing $1"
  aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $1 --zip-file fileb://./dist/src.zip
}    
publish endpoint1
publish endpoint2
```

and this is how I am calling it from the makefile:

```
deploy_staging: dist/src.zip
    ./deploy.sh
```

wonder why Make complains about the "}" character, I expected the content of the script to be hidden or isolated from the point of view of the makefile.

Comment: Does your script have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang?  the `make` shell defaults to `/bin/sh` - which is `dash` on Ubuntu. See [GNU make: Choosing the Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html)

Comment: nope! and it worked as expected after I added it. thank you so much, if you post your comment as an answer I will be more than glad to mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it was closed before I managed to finish writing my answer - I'm not sure why @muru since the suggested duplicate doesn't refer to `make` at all?

Comment: @steeldriver I saw the usual beaten-to-death missing shebang problem and simply closed it. If you have a solution specific to Makefiles, I'll reopen.

Comment: @muru I agree the solution is the same here - but aren't we supposed to close based on duplicate *questions*, rather than duplicate *answers*?

Comment: @steeldriver any number of variations of the missing shebang problem are possible for each feature that bash has and sh doesn't. That is: the *underlying* problem is the same. So, AFAIAC, the question is the same. I don't see a need for separate questions on the `function` keyword, brace expansion, the `HOSTNAME` variable, process substitution and who knows how many other features.

Comment: @steeldriver That said, if you have a solution specific to Make, I'll reopen